# Creating a Master excel file from dynamic CSV output using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to create a repository "Master" excel file from a CSV which will be generated and overwritten every couple of hours. The code below creates a new excel file and writes the content from "combo1.csv" to "master.xlsx". However, whenever the combo1 file is updated, the code basically overwrites the contents in the "master.xlsx" file. I need to append the contents from "combo1" to "Master" without the headers being inserted every time. Can someone help me with this?

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('master.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df = pd.read_csv('combo1.csv')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheetname')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Try with write_to_excel() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to **Append Data at the End of an Excel Sheet** section in this medium article:
[Using Python Pandas with Excel Sheets](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-python-pandas-with-excel-d5082102ca27)

(Credit to *Nensi Trambadiya* for the article)

Basically you'll have to first read the Excel file and find the number of rows before pushing the new data.

```
reader = pd.read_excel(r'master.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1)
```

Comment: I used the code in this "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Trambadiya26Nensi/a31d186f1aba549b3fef0f7b55945e20/raw/b610cdba0f06a6a6c4b546a3cb69836d546021c7/appenddata.py" and replaced the first dataframe with "df=pd.read_csv('combo1.csv')". I get an error stating that the demo.xlsx file is not available

Comment: shouldn't you use your own Excel sheet there? for example, 'master.xlsx' ?

Comment: There is no master for now, I want to first Create a master, next add whatever is in Combo1 to master. The contents of Combo1 will change every 2 hours, so whenever the script is initiated, I want the contents of Combo1 to be appended to the already existing content in Master. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: you have to use your 'master.xlsx' instead of 'demo.xlsx'

Comment: Okay. I understood now that I would need to create a Master.xlsx file before running the script. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

First read the excel file and then need to perform below method to append the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter import load_workbook

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['abc','def','xyz','ysv'],
                   'Age': [08,45,32,26]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('master.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

writer.book = load_workbook('Master.xlsx')

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)

reader = pd.read_excel(r'master.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1)

writer.close()
```

Comment: I get an attribute error  "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write_to_excel'".

Comment: python version?

Comment: python 3. Specifically 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# new dataframe with same columns
df = pd.read_csv('combo.csv')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('master.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
# try to open an existing workbook
writer.book = load_workbook('master.xlsx')
# copy existing sheets
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
# read existing file
reader = pd.read_excel(r'master.xlsx')
# write out the new sheet
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader) + 1)

writer.close()
```

Note that a Master has to be created before running the script